# Black screen after reboot on ubuntu desktop (Raspi 4)

Tags: 20.04, desktop-environments, remote-desktop, raspberrypi

I have a fresh raspberry pi 4 with a ubuntu desktop install created using [desktopify](https://github.com/wimpysworld/desktopify). However, after rebooting the device, I do not see a login screen, just a black screen.

Build steps I took:

- I have flashed the sd card with the ubuntu 20.04 server install using
  the rapsberry pi imager utility.
- Logged in and set a new password.
- Updated all packages using

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt upgrade -y git`

Then installed ubuntu desktop as follows:

`clone https://github.com/wimpysworld/desktopify.git`

`cd desktopify`

`sudo ./desktopify --de ubuntu`

`sudo reboot`

During reboot, text is shown on the connected screen. I also see a spinning ubuntu logo. But then the screen goes black. No inputs from keyboard or mouse have any effect. The hardware itself appears fine as I can do all the above physically attached to the pi4. I can ssh to the pi4 just fine from another machine.

Having searched elsewhere there were mentions of changes required to config.txt file. However, I do not seem to have one:

`ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ less  /boot/config.txt`

```
/boot/config.txt: No such file or directory
```

I am unsure of what to try next.

Ultimately, I am trying to build a ubuntu install on the pi4 that I can remote desktop to, where I can interact with GUI applications like IntelliJ for java tinkering, from any other machine on my network. Of course, I could use just the terminal, but I would like the convenience of a GUI experience also. As far as I can tell, a remote desktop capability can only be enabled from an active ubuntu desktop session using a physically enabled screen keyboard. Once this done, I will only connect remotely from windows machines.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I reflashed the card, and installed ubuntu desktop, rebooted and it just worked.

`sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

`sudo reboot`